# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ in tests fails

Tags: maven, java-8, gson, junit4, cobertura

I'm having a problem with running the tests. Currently, I'm running the tests with **maven** and the **cobertura** plugin and I'm stumbling upon the following problem (several times):

```
DifferentObjectsAreNotEqual(game.PlayerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.006 sec  <<< ERROR!
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:899)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:825)
        at game.Game.build(Game.java:76)
        at game.Game.<init>(Game.java:45)
        at game.PlayerTest.setUp(PlayerTest.java:18)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:70)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
        ... 33 more
```

The weird part is, when I run these tests in **IntelliJ**, it runs properly. This is the setup of the `PlayerTest`:

```
@Before    // Line 16
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Game game = new Game();
    Player1 = new Player(game);
    Player2 = new Player(game);
}
```

It seems that the problem occurs at the `Game game = new Game();` part. This is the **Game** class constructor:

```
/**
 * Constructs a new single-player game.
 */
public Game() {      // Line 31
    date = new Date();
    season = 1;
    race = 1;

    players = new Player[11];
    players[0] = new Player(this);

    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 1; i < players.length; i++) {
        players[i] = new Computer(this, random);
    }

    constructors = build(Constructor.DATA_PATH, Constructor[].class);
    drivers = build(Driver.DATA_PATH, Driver[].class);

    strategists = new ArrayList<>(TOTAL_STAFF);
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_STAFF; i++) {
        strategists.add(new Strategist(random));
    }

    mechanics = new ArrayList<>(TOTAL_STAFF);
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_STAFF; i++) {
        mechanics.add(new Mechanic(random));
    }

    aerodynamicists = new ArrayList<>(TOTAL_STAFF);
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_STAFF; i++) {
        aerodynamicists.add(new Aerodynamicist(random));
    }

    engines = build(Engine.DATA_PATH, Engine[].class);
    tires = build(Tire.DATA_PATH, Tire[].class);
}
```

The problem seems to be at the line with `drivers = build(Driver.DATA_PATH, Driver[].class);`. That means that the constructor itself works, but the driver doesn't. This is the `build` method:

```
/**
 * Builds a {@link List} from a JSON file, should replace the {@link game.Builder} eventually.
 * @param path The path to the resource
 * @param arrayType The class type
 * @return The list of objects from the JSON
 */
private List build(String path, Class<? extends Object[]> arrayType) {   // Line 72
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(getClass().getResource(path).getFile());
        List result = new ArrayList();
        result.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(reader, arrayType)));
        return result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Is this a problem related with Cobertura and Maven, or is this a problem with the code itself? I don't think there is a problem with the **json** file itself because they have practically the same syntax as the other json files.

Comment: To help debugging maybe you can print the getFile value of the resource at the beginning of your build method. With maven maybe the class isn't executed from the same folder as in IntelliJ...

Comment: @Bludwarf Hmm, good point. I'll check on that now, thanks.

Comment: @Bludwarf I just checked and they both have the same path file: `/client/target/classes/data/*.json`, so that couldn't be it.

Comment: OK for the path but you can check the 2nd part of my answer. When you call getClass().getResource() it refers to the executed .class file. Maybe maven generates class in another folder than IntelliJ. Also a good approach would be to print the JSON content of the file before parsing it (with Apache IOUtils for instance).

Comment: @Bludwarf I have just checked and both Maven and IntelliJ use the same folder for the classes, so this also couldn't be it. I'll try to print the JSON but I'm not sure how to do it. I'll try to update this later.

Comment: You can try this : `InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
    System.out.println(IOUtils.toString());
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);`. Good luck ;)